# using javascript to secure directory with http basic auth

Tags: javascript, authentication

I have a directory that is currently just protected with http basic auth and was wondering if I could authenticate with http basic auth using javascript. I would just like put up a simple form asking for a username and password to unlock a directory. I am not looking for a hardened security solution since all this does is serve up basic html pages, but I would like to secure it enough to keep random eyes out of it. It is just a basic site that is used to house some proof of concept UI ideas for the department I work at, but needs to be available outside of our corporate network since we use it at trade shows and such. Is there anyway to toss a simple form in front of it that would authenticate with http basic auth? This is all hosted behind IIS 7 at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean basic auth completely in JavaScript? As in JavaScript checks if the username and password are correct? That is very easily worked around, I wouldn't consider that security at all.

Comment: I mean by submitting the username/password to a web server that is using http basic auth. I would have a form that would send the username/password to the webserver. Right now I just have basic auth turn on for the directory and it pops up with the browser dialogue.